# Proving a set has measure zero if there is a cover with volume

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I want to prove the statement that "a set $A$ has measure zero iff for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a covering of $A$ by sets $V_1, V_2, \cdots$ with volume such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty vol(V_i) < \epsilon$".

Now, the converse is pretty simple to prove since it corresponds to the definition. But I ran into some technical difficulty proving the other half of the statement: is it mathematically correct to claim that "If there is a covering of $A$ by sets $V_1,V_2,\cdots$ with volume such that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty vol(V_i) < \epsilon$ for every $\epsilon > 0$, then there exists a set of boxes $\left\{ Q^\epsilon_{m_j} \right\}_{m=1}^{N_j}$ such that $V_j \subset \bigcup_{m=1}^{N_j} Q^\epsilon_{m_j}$ and $\sum_{m=1}^{N_j} vol \left( Q^\epsilon_{m_j} \right) < \frac\epsilon{4^j}$"? Then it follows that
$$
A \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty V_j \subset \bigcup_{j=1}^\infty \bigcup_{m=1}^{N_j} Q^\epsilon_{m_j} \ \text{and} \ \sum_{j=1}^\infty \sum_{m=1}^{N_j} vol \left( Q^\epsilon_{m_j} \right) < \sum_{j=1}^\infty \frac\epsilon{4^j} = \frac\epsilon3 < \epsilon
$$
So $A$ has measure $0$.

Comment: I think this is right - the usual definition of measure 0 I have seen skips the volume of the sets and goes straight to boxes , i.e. we have a box cover whose total volume is at most epsilon.

Comment: That's exactly what I am trying to prove here: replacing regular boxes with any sets with volume in the definition.

Comment: I think what you're doing is correct - it basically comes down to the fact that a cover with arbitrarily small volume must be consituted of sets with arbitrarily small volume, which in turn are covered by countably covers of rectangles, each with arbitrarily small volume. My only concern with the rigor of your proof is is taking the cover of boxes for each $V_i$ to be finite - they need not be finite (right?) For example if the set $V_1$ is some infinite subset of the rational numbers.

Comment: I think according to the definition of "volume" that I am working with, i.e. the integral of the characteristic function of the set, the cover of boxes has to be finite. Am I correct here?

Comment: I am not sure, because at first you use an infinite sum $\sum_{i = 1}^\infty \mathrm{Vol}(R_i)$. May I ask - under your definition what would the volume of the set $\mathbb{Q}$ be?

Comment: The volume of $\mathbb{Q}$ would be the value of the integral of the characteristic function over some box that contains $\mathbb{Q}$. i.e. $\int_Q \chi_Q$. Also, I used an infinite sum at first because the definition of Lebesgue measure allows for countable cover.

Comment: Right - so if you are using Lebesgue measure, the cover of boxes is countably-infinite. Otherwise the integral above would not converge.

Comment: So just to clarify, it is mathematically rigorous to use a finite cover for each of the $V_i$'s, i.e. if a set has volume, it has a finite cover. Also, the counterexample that you gave above (an infinite subset of the rational numbers) does not volume since its characteristic function would have infinitely many discontinuities.